# How to preserve sourcemaps from Babel transpiling to r.js uglifying?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, ecmascript-6, r.js, babeljs

I'm writing ES6 JavaScript modules and using Babel to transpile them to ES5. Babel generates sourcemaps that point back to the original ES6 code. I then use r.js to take those ES5 AMD modules and combine and uglify them. r.js creates a sourcemap that shows the ES5 files. I want the ES6 ones from the first step. My grunt file looks like this:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt); // npm install --save-dev load-grunt-tasks

  // Project configuration.
  grunt.initConfig({
    babel: {
      options: {
        modules: "amd",
        sourceMap: true
      },
      dist: {
        files: {
          "es5/editor.js": "src/editor.js",
          "es5/editor-events.js": "src/editor-events.js"
        }
      }
    },
    requirejs: {
      production: {
        options: {
          baseUrl: "es5",
          mainConfigFile: "es5/require.config.js",
          name: "../node_modules/almond/almond",
          include: ["editor"],
          out: "dist/ed.js",
          optimize: "uglify2",
          generateSourceMaps: true,
          preserveLicenseComments: false
        }
      }
    }
  });

  // Default task(s).
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['babel', 'requirejs']);

};
```

It compiles everything perfectly. But it loses the nice ES6 sourcemaps. Any way to keep them? Is there a better build process that'll get me to a single, browser-friendly JavaScript file?

Answer (score -1):

you shouldn't use two different steps for building your app. one for transpiling and an other one for bundling. you should have one step instead.

you could use `browserify` to bundle them and `babelify` as transpiler. the command would look like this:

```
browserify app.js -t babelify -d -o bundle.js
```

> Note: `-d` (debug) will enable the sourcemaps. they will point to the es6 files.